# Inconsistent errors with Rspec, Capybara and phantom.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec, capybara, phantomjs

I have a pretty basic test that sometimes works, and sometimes fails with inconsistent error messages such as:

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
      The action 'location_states' could not be found for LocationController
```

Or:

```
Failure/Error: select 'Nationwide', from: 'location_type'
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find option "Nationwide"
```

Or:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     RuntimeError:
       Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant LocationOptions
```

The AJAX callback that calls location_states to initialize the `location_type` dropdown is in an Angular scope, so I'm wondering if that's why there's this inconsistent behavior. I tried increasing `Capybara.default_wait_time` to 10, but that didn't seem to change anything.

The specific line that seems to be causing all of this:

`select 'Nationwide', from: 'location_type'`

since Capybara's select ultimately relies on `find`, I thought I wouldn't run into synchronization issues, but I guess I'm missing something here.

I'm using the phantom.js driver through [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist).

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I am having the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem using rspec, capybara, and poltergeist. Capybara is reporting that it cannot find an element that is clearly on the page. I use save_and_open_page and verify that it is there. Of course, when I put a "sleep 5" statement before my "page.find(:css, '#element_id')", well then the test passes.

Comment: I ended up finding a way to fix this without relying on sleep / pausing mechanisms, I'll post an answer tonight.